# Cannot delete old NFS directory: Device or resource busy

Tags: fedora, nfs, mount

On server1, we had an NFS share mounted from server2 like this:

```
/nfs/server2/share
```

Recently, we took down server2 to install a new OS on it. Now we can't get NFS setup the way it was. When I do this:

```
ls -l /nfs/server2
```

and it's empty. So therefore I cannot mount my share at `/nfs/server2/share`.

When I try to create `/nfs/server2/share` directory, I get

```
mkdir: cannot create directory `share': No such file or directory
```

I think this is because it doesn't really think the `/nfs/server2` directory really exists. Even if I use the -p option with mkdir, it doesn't work.

Next I tried to remove `/nfs/server2` so I could just recreate it. I try to rm -r `/nfs/server2` but I get

```
rm: cannot remove directory `/nfs/server2': Device or resource busy
```

So now I'm at a loss. I need to mount this NFS share in the same exact place on `server1` (at `/nfs/server2/share`) because other software on server1 depend on this. But if I can't create that share directory and I can't remove that directory, what do I do?

Also, just for testing, I attempted to mount the share at `/nfs/testing/share` and it mounted just fine. But like I said, I need to mount it back in the same location.

**UPDATE**

The server2 is not mounted in any way on server1. I think that the problem started when another admin took down server2 to reinstall the OS without first unmounting the share on server1. I'm not sure if that makes a difference or not. In any case, `mount | grep server2` shows nothing and there is nothing in `fstab`.

**SOLVED**

Apparently automount was running on server1 and that service was keeping me from deleting that old NFS directory. Lack-of-communication-between-sysadmins FTL...

I suppose that the way to solve this problem would have been to grep for some process or service that is using that directory I tried to delete. But I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future reference, the `mount --move` switch is very useful to move a misbehaving mount out of the way.  See also the `umount -l` option.

Answer (score 0):

You can find out what processes are using what files with `lsof(1)`.

You will need to run this as root to access all the information about processes on your machine.

Unix treats almost everything as files , so you can also get a list of network resources in use.

Try:

```
lsof | grep TCP
```

a great diagnostic tool!

Answer (score 0):

To view current mounts, look in `/etc/mtab`, not `/etc/fstab`.  `/etc/fstab` shows what the machine tries to mount at system start.  `/etc/mtab` is a dynamic file that shows what is mounted NOW.  For example, the `mount` command, without any options, shows current mounts.  The information is provided by reading `/etc/mtab`.  So now you have TWO ways to see what is mounted.  They also show you all the options for each mount, including the default ones, which do not show in `/etc/fstab`.